# Calculating the number of records after doing a GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

Is there a way in SQL to count the number of records in a given record set that already has had a `GROUP BY` applied to it?

I have a table that contains a weekly summary of wins, ties and losses for all users in a series of games. It looks sort of like this:

```
userid  weekid  wins  losses  ties
1       1       10    5       2
1       2       11    3       3
1       3       8     9       0
2       1       11    6       0
2       2       7     9       1
2       3       9     7       1
3       1       3     14      0
3       2       7     9       1
3       3       6     9       2
```

I want to determine the rank of a given user. I would do this by counting the number of users with a better combination of wins, ties and losses than that user. If I wanted to determine the rank of user #3 for example, I could use this query, but it only gets me half way there:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) 
FROM scores
GROUP BY userid
HAVING (SUM(wins) * 2) + SUM(ties) > 35
```

The result would look like this:

```
COUNT(userid)
3
3
```

What this gives me is a record set containing 2 records (meaning he ranks third). What I would really like is just the number of records (2) rather than the records themselves. The only thing I can think of is to dump the record set to a temporary table and do the `COUNT()` there, but that's pretty expensive. Or I can hand the data set back to C# and do the record count there, but if the given user has a terrible record, the number of records I need to send gets quite huge.

I'm hoping there's a relatively cheap way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
(
    SELECT (SUM(wins) * 2) + SUM(ties) as Rank
    FROM scores
    GROUP BY userid
) tt
WHERE Rank > 35
```