# SQL command that count number of rows after group by c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table called Order(Id,Number,Date).
"Id" and "Number" are main keys.

table Order

```
Id Number Date
0   1     1995   
0   2     1995        
0   3     1995   
1   1     1999   
1   2     1999   
2   1     2001
```

I need the number of rows but without duplicates (in this example: 3 ) 
I know that the "group by Id" will give me: Id(0,1,2)
but I cant count it after the group by.

Comment: Did you check this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449243/calculating-the-number-of-records-after-doing-a-group-by-in-sql

Comment: You need the number of rows with unique Id? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I looked for a lot of ways but they wont work, it always give me an error or the wrong number of rows.
I only need the Id column without duplicates and then count the rows of the Id column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(distinct id) from order
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [SQL Fiddle working code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d502/15), it returns what you are looking for. It groups by `Number` and then counts the total of rows, on this case, 3 rows.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I see you are counting by ID, modified the code. Nevertheless is the same logic just different column.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Rows_count
FROM (
      SELECT COUNT([Id]) count_rows
        FROM tOrder
       GROUP BY [Id]) AS T1
```

Result:

```
ROWS_COUNT
   3
```

**EDIT**

This code works too indeed and is shorter. My previous one helps if you need to add a `HAVING` clause after the `GROUP BY` in case you want some particular value to be counted or not.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM [Order]
```

Comment: thank you! it works , i"m sorry but the above answer is better for me

Comment: Yes, you are correct, check my edit. My initial code helps if you need to filter some particular value, for example, `HAVING ID > 1` or alike

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

select DISTINCT COUNT(Id) from Order